# Allow a poster who saw their question closed by a dupehammer to state that they accept that it is a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

If a user votes to close a question as a duplicate, and that user doesn't have a dupehammer that can close the question right away, the user who posted it has the possibility of accepting that the answer is a duplicate. And that acceptance becomes visible, besides the fact that then the question gets immediately closed.

I suggest that an acceptance button could also exist when a question gets closed by someone with a dupehammer. In that case, its only effect it would have would be to make visible the fact that the person who posted the question agrees that it is a duplicate. But that's much simpler than having to write a comment stating that, and it would provide feedback to the owner of the dupehammer.

Comment: But for future visitors there is no difference. And if one really wants to let the closer know you appreciate their help, it's possible to leave a short lived comment. What's to be gained by this?

Comment: Many users who would not spend some time writing a comment, will have no problem with pressing an acceptance button. And future visiotrs will know that the person who asked the question agrees that it is a duplicate.

Comment: But that's not useful for future visitors. Future visitors are looking for answers to their questions, not to know who voted what. Allowing the asker to "accept" a dupe before it's closed is useful because it allows for speedier closing. But after the fact, there is no upshot.

Comment: I fully agree that it is less useful than an usual closing vote as a duplicate. But it provides an easy way to provide *some* feedback to the person who closed the question.

Comment: It's probably useful for future stats though. The only time we hear of dupehammer closes is when people are complaining about them.

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of allowing the OP to confirm closure is to get the question closed and thereby get the link to the answer in place.

So given that, why display the acceptance at all of the OP confirming question closure? And the answer to that is that we want an explainable system i.e. we don't want people eternally asking meta questions along the lines of "How did this question become closed with insufficient votes?"

If the OP disagrees with the closure they can and should simply edit the question to explain why the duplicate does not answer their question. That will put the question in the reopen queue. They can also cast a reopen vote if they have the requisite privilege to do so.

Not editing the question implies that they are satisfied with the duplicate so no further action is required.